# Can't pass two numerical arguments with docopt package

Tags: r, docopt

In creating a command line tool using R, I decided to use the [docopt package](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R). It works for passing flags, but I can't figure out how to pass two numeric values. See the below code:

```
#! /usr/bin/Rscript

'usage: ./test.R [-lr <low> -hr <high>]

options:
 -h --help         Shows this screen
 -lr --low <low>         Passes low risk investiment
 -hr --high <high>        Passes high risk investiment' -> doc

library(docopt)
# retrieve the command-line arguments
opts <- docopt(doc)
# what are the options? Note that stripped versions of the parameters are added to the returned list
cat(opts$high)
cat(opts$low)
str(opts)
```

Whenever I try to run using `./test.R -lr 2000 -hr 4000` it warns me that the methods package is being loaded and returns nothing else.

- What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `-h` is specified twice: once for "help", another for "high", so you'll run into problems there. To fix this, I'll use upper-case letters for the short arguments. Second, the argument to an option must either be in `<angular-brackets>` or UPPER-CASE, so `-lr` doesn't work. (Apparently it also needs a space between the option and its argument.) I'll expand it to be the same named arguments as for the long options.

Additionally (though perhaps not strictly required), I think a comma helps clarify things. (**Edit**: apparently `docopt.R` doesn't like the leading `./` on usage, so I've updated the output.)

```
usage: test.R [-L <low> -H <high>]

options:
 -h, --help                 Shows this screen
 -L <low>, --low <low>     Passes low risk investiment
 -H <high>, --high <high>  Passes high risk investiment
```

(I found the requirements for `docopt` at http://docopt.org/. I found that their [interactive docopt demo](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=usage%3A+.%2Ftest.R+%5B-L+%3Clow%3E+-H+%3Chigh%3E%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aoptions%3A%0D%0A+-h+--help++++++++++++++++Shows+this+screen%0D%0A+-L+%3Clow%3E%2C+--low+%3Clow%3E++++Passes+low+risk+investiment%0D%0A+-H+%3Chigh%3E%2C+--high+%3Chigh%3E++Passes+high+risk+investiment&argv=--low+10+--high+32) worked quite well, too.)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, however it must be a bug in R (R version 3.4.1) with docopt from CRAN, because it does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I initially interpreted it as a problem with docopt in general (with which your original version is not compatible), not with the R implementation (which appears to choke with either version). I see you've [already filed a bug report](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R/issues/32), way ahead of me.

Comment: I found the error. The R iteration of docopt does not handle the ./test.R at the usage section, it must be test.R